# Configuring azure site-to-site VPN with another network

Tags: vpn, azure, vlan

I have an Azure VM (resource manager) already existing in a VLAN and i would like to know how can i setup a site to site connection.

I have read https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell/ but it does not explain on setting up on an existing VLAN plus it did not seem clear to me (or easy to understand).

I am trying to achieve something like what is explained here https://github.com/Azure/Azure-vpn-config-samples/blob/master/Cisco/ASA_9.1_and_above_Static_Routing.pdf on my existing VLAN (with a VM)

Answer (score 0):

First I downloaded the latest version of the Azure Resource Manager PowerShell cmdlets to configure connection, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/ on how to download and install.

I took the following steps

1. Connect to your subscription

   ```
       Login-AzureRmAccount
   ```
2. Added a gateway subnet to the VNet since i did not have one,I first took the VNet as a variable then added gateway. Note you MUST to name the gateway subnet "GatewaySubnet"

   ```
   $vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName testrg -Name testvnet
   Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'GatewaySubnet' -AddressPrefix 10.0.3.0/28 -VirtualNetwork $vnet
   ```
3. Request a public IP address for the gateway, this is different from the VM public IP

   ```
   $gwpip= New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name gwpip -ResourceGroupName testrg -Location 'West US' -AllocationMethod Dynamic
   ```
4. Create the gateway IP addressing configuration

   $vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name testvnet -ResourceGroupName testrg
    $subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'GatewaySubnet' -VirtualNetwork $vnet
    $gwipconfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig -Name gwipconfig1 -SubnetId $subnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $gwpip.Id
5. Create the gateway

   ```
      New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway -Name vnetgw1 -ResourceGroupName testrg -Location 'West US' -IpConfigurations $gwipconfig -GatewayType Vpn -VpnType RouteBased
   ```

For information on how to create a virtual network with a site-to-site VPN (resource manager)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell/